# Increasing ul auto height with animation on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new bee. I want to make a ul increasing auto height with animation on page load. Is it possible in css? Please help me.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">title 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">title 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">title 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">title 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">title 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is possible, but you probably want to do something else. You can animate height from one value to the next. I think that what you look is in this tutorial. http://designmodo.com/create-css3-mega-menu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this purely in CSS, thereby maintaining a **strict and proper separation of concerns** meaning all styling is kept within the boundaries/scope of your CSS:

```css
ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    max-height: 0
  }
  to {
    max-height: 200px
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes grow {
  from {
    max-height: 0
  }
  to {
    max-height: 200px
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">title 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">title 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">title 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">title 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">title 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @SureshKumar - simple, you need to change `height` to `max-height`, in the above, simply replace `200px` for the largest forseeable potential height. Note that the element wont grow to that height, it will only grow to the height needed for its contents, up to that value. As such, the element will only grow as high as its contents.